# How to save JSON object to text file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tuples, keypoint

this is the full code i'm trying to run

```
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('figure.jpg')
detector = MTCNN()
face = detector.detect_faces(image)
for face in faces:
    print(face)
```

this is the resulted JSON object:

```
{'box': [141, 106, 237, 292], 'confidence': 0.9988177418708801, 'keypoints': {'left_eye': (211, 218), 'right_eye': (321, 219), 'nose': (265, 278), 'mouth_left': (209, 319), 'mouth_right': (319, 324)}}
```

than

```
import json
json_result = {}
with open("result.txt,"w") as result_file:
    for n,face in enumerate(faces):
    json_result[str(n)] = face
    json_string = json.dumps(json_result, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    result_file.write(json_string)
```

I get a result txt file that looks like this:

```
{
    "0": {
        "box": [
            142,
            109,
            237,
            289
        ],
        "confidence": 0.9997594952583313,
        "keypoints": {
            "left_eye": [
                212,
                221
            ],
            "mouth_left": [
                209,
                322
            ],
            "mouth_right": [
                319,
                327
            ],
            "nose": [
                265,
                280
            ],
            "right_eye": [
                323,
                223
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But what I need is a result that looks like this:

```
142.84  207.18
222.02  203.9
159.24  253.57
146.59  290.93
227.52  284.74
```

How can I translate my keypoints to a format in 2 columns and also omit 'box' and 'confidence' ?

I tried to get a text file containing 5 landmarks from a JSON object generated from mtcnn.

Comment: Do you keep the json object in `json_result` variable?

Comment: @ilyasbbu thank you for your reply. I am not a programmer, so i don't know what you mean. I have a longer code in a jupyter notebook from the MTCNN git and what i posted here is the last part. The JSON object is resulted from "faces = detector.detect_faces(image) / for face in faces: / print(face)"

Answer (score 1):

First to omit `box` and `confidence`:

```py
faces = faces['keypoints']
```

This will give you a JSON object as:

```
{'left_eye': (211, 218), 'right_eye': (321, 219), 'nose': (265, 278), 'mouth_left': (209, 319), 'mouth_right': (319, 324)}
```

Then to write in file:

```py
with open("result.txt","w") as result_file:
    for face in faces:
        json_string = faces[face]
        json_string = " ".join([str(i) for i in json_string])
        result_file.write(json_string)
```

will give you output:

```
211 218
321 219
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ilyasbbu! Can you tell me where i should put "faces = faces [ 'keypoints' ]" ?

Comment: Before `with open( ....`

Comment: Thank you for your help @lyasbbu! i changed "faces = faces ['keypoints]" to "faces = face['keypoints']" becouse i was getting this " KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In [11], line 1
----> 1 faces = faces['keypoints'] KeyError: 'keypoints' ". And now i get a result but it looks like this "212 221323 223265 280209 322319 327" .